# Place div-box in bigger div box on the right top

Tags: html, css, layout

is there any possibility to place a smaller div-box into a bigger one, on the right top?
So that there still can be text in the bigger div, left of the smaller one?

```
|----------------------------|
| Random text      |------|  |
|                  |blabl |  |
|                  |------|  |
|                            |
|                            |
|----------------------------|
```

Thanks

Comment: yes it is. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: yeah, but it all didn't work and i don't think that it helps to post it here. I wasn't that succesfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```css
.big-box{
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:10px;
}
.small-box{
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:10px;
  float:right;  
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box">
  <div class="small-box">
    contents of small box
  </div>
  Contents of big box.<br/>
  multiple lines<br/>
  multiple lines<br/>
  multiple lines<br/>
  multiple lines<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, but somehow it doesn't work for me, i have to headlines <h3> and <h4> in my big-box and they get bushed down by the small box

Comment: sadly i can't reproduce it in jsfiddle :D Maybe a css mistake on my headlines?

Comment: very strange, because here in jfiddle with the css-file i use, it does work but in my whole project it doesnt. Confused. http://jsfiddle.net/s4xae669/

Comment: nevermind, i found the mistake: it was the clear:both statement in my headlines. Thanks!